# Appendix numbering (Alph.arabic) in Latex

Tags: appendices

I'm trying to have a appendix as

Appendix A

A.1
A.2
A.3

This is what I have do so far

```
\appendix
%\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
```

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here??

Thank you

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: For `article` the `A.1` numbering style is the default as soon as `\appendix` and `\subsection` is used, there is no need of redefinition of the `\the...` macros. It requires a non-zero section counter value however, since `\Alph{section}` outputs nothing if section is zero

Answer (score 4):

If the `article` class is used, there is no need of `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{...}` since `\appendix` redefines `\thesection` to use `\Alph` etc.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\appendix

\section{An appendix section}
\subsection{An appendix subsection}
\subsection{Another appendix subsection}
\section{Another appendix section}
\subsection{Just another appendix subsection}
\subsection{Yet Another appendix subsection}

This is an appendix.
\end{document}
```

[image]